# Growing controller constructor using DI MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a controller that has methods tied to buttons that do different processes for a single collection of data but it has been slowly growing. Not even send file method is always called for each collection of data. Sometimes only 1 out of the 3 are needed but we want each file format to have its own button on the client.

```
public AController(
        ILogger logger,
        IabcRepository abcRepo,
        IFileService<FileTypeA> fileTypeAService,
        IFileService<FileTypeB> fileTypeBService,
        IFileService<FileTypeC> fileTypeCService,
        IPrintService printFileService,
        ....
        )

public ActionResult SendFileA(int id)
{
   _fileTypeAService.SendFile(id);
   _abcRepo.Update(id)
   _logger.Log("log message");
}

public ActionResult SendFileB(id)
{
   _fileTypeBService.SendFile(id);
   _abcRepo.Update(id)
   _logger.Log("log message");
}

public ActionResult SendFileC(int id)
{
   _fileTypeCService.SendFile(id);
   _abcRepo.Update(id)
   _logger.Log("log message");
}

public ActionResult PrintFileC(int id)
{
   _printFileService.PrintFile(id);
   _abcRepo.Update(id)
   _logger.Log("log message");
}
```

These methods are all called in succession of the previous method and only allow the user to click on the button if the previous method successfully worked.

File types A, B, and C are formatted differently and the file that is printed is not any of those files.

Does this need refactoring and what would be the best way pattern/method of doing so?

Comment: When you say that only one out of three are needed, what does that mean? Does it mean that a given controller will have dependencies that are never used? Or does it mean that a given user might use one but not others, but all three need to be there?

Comment: @ScottHannen so the data that gets processed by these buttons comes in from another process but the data comes from different sources. It's the same data but sometimes it doesn't need to go through all the same processing. The buttons are built dynamically based on where the data came from so the person won't always see all 5 buttons but sometimes just 3.

Comment: Take a look at the concept of the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). A class with many dependencies likely violates this principle. Another way of looking at this, is from the concept of cohesion. If the methods in a class are not cohesive, this is another indication that the class might violate SRP. In that case its good to split the class up into multiple, smaller, more focussed classes